# Error: Token Mismatch from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, macos-sierra

I have installed an AMP stack on my computer running macOS 10.12. I've installed phpMyAdmin and configured it as follows:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'jdhsuebdiso37281649021se3hvbsoei';
$i = 0; 
$i++; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false; 
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

After starting my MySQL server, I would try to login to phpMyAdmin but the login page would keep repeating with no error whenever I submit the login form. I switched the `auth_type` to `'http'` to see if I could see any errors and I the `Error: Token Mismatch` error appeared. After reading several StackExchange questions and answers as well as several forum posts, I've done the following trouble shooting steps:

- Set `session.save_path = "/tmp"` in php.ini
- Set `session.save_path = "/private/tmp"` in php.ini
- Ran the `df` command and got the following output:
  [image: df output]
- Restarting my Apache server
- Reinstalling phpMyAdmin and MySQL
- Access MySQL successfully through the command line.
- `<?php phpinof();` works fine
- mcrypt is installed

Are there any other troubleshooting steps I could try?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it pertains to trying to set up software, not actual programming.

Comment: Do try and break this down into smaller steps, like connecting via MySQL Workbench instead of the phpMyAdmin tool.

Comment: @tadman ServerFault said this was off topic as well. Where would this be on topic? Also, I have connected to MySQL via the terminal and it works without a problem.

Comment: You probably want to check that you can run PHP at all, like with a quick `<?php phpinfo() ?>` script to exercise it. This is a tech support issue with phpMyAdmin if everything else checks out.

Comment: I have tried that and PHP works fine. I have mcrypt installed too.

Comment: If you're really stuck you may need to dig into the source of phpMyAdmin and find out what it's doing that generates that error. It could be a bug.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version is this?

Comment: @MarcDelisle It is version 4.7.1